# find group by clause error programmatically

Tags: sql, database, oracle, group-by

We are going to update our database from 10g to 12c. Before doing so we need to revisit our SQLs, and as a part of this we need to check the following behavior of `GROUP BY`

**case 1:**

```
SELECT abcd_pk,
  COUNT(abcd_code),
  ABCD_COUNT
FROM
  (SELECT abcd_pk,
    abcd_code,
    (SELECT COUNT(abcd_code) FROM ABCD_TABLE
    ) "ABCD_COUNT"
  FROM ABCD_TABLE
  )
GROUP BY abcd_pk, ABCD_COUNT ;
```

1. WORKS IN 10G
2. WORKS IN 12C

**case 2:**

```
SELECT abcd_pk,
  COUNT(abcd_code),
  ABCD_COUNT
FROM
  (SELECT abcd_pk,
    abcd_code,
    (SELECT COUNT(abcd_code) FROM ABCD_TABLE
    ) "ABCD_COUNT"
  FROM ABCD_TABLE
  )
GROUP BY abcd_pk ;
```

1. WORKS IN 10G
2. DOES NOT WORK IN 12C (ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression")

Our code may contains case2 like SQL which is not appropriate. So we need to identify those SQLs. I already prepared a list of SQLs contains `GROUP BY` used in our project (.java files/procedure/function/views etc.).

Requirement is find the problem in `GROUP BY` using the following process:

1. Check the SQLs in the list one by one.
2. Find an alternate way to check the list of SQLs programmatically.

Option 1 requires massive work load, effort and time, but I think option 2 is not possible.

Is there any suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: I'd say stick with case 1 anyway. You'll never go wrong if you follow the general GROUP BY rule - "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround which might work would be to place the count subquery into an aggregate function, e.g. `AVG()`:

```
SELECT abcd_pk,
       COUNT(abcd_code),
       AVG(ABCD_COUNT)      -- use an aggregate to not offend Oracle
FROM
(
    SELECT abcd_pk,
           abcd_code,
           (SELECT COUNT(abcd_code) FROM ABCD_TABLE) "ABCD_COUNT"
    FROM ABCD_TABLE
)
GROUP BY abcd_pk;
```

If this fixes the problem, then it means that Oracle's treatment of subqueries resulting in constants has changed between `10G` and `12C`.

Comment: Yes, you are right but my question is not that. I know case2 is incorrect & case1 is correct. We already have some SQLs in our code like case2, previously it worked in 10g but currently not working in 12c. So we want to change all case2 like SQLs to case1. So first of all we need to identify those SQLs. My question is how to find all such SQLs like case2?

Comment: This is a much harder question to answer and illustrates the value of trying to keep queries as ANSI compliant as possible.  Had you done so, the change in version would not have broken anything.